# Postgres DB performance issue

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4, postgresql-10, postgresql-performance

I'm suspecting our Postgres DB has performance issue so I'm troubleshooting.

First I'm running a query below from my local laptop like below;

```
 "select * from table1"
```

And this table has 7 rows and it taks around 506 ms, seems slow.

[image]

So after then I run the query below;

```
 EXPLAIN ANALYZE select * from table1;
```

Output is below;

[image]

So if I'm correct, output says query took 0.008 second?

So how can I understand these values? Are these values ok?

Ps : Postgresql ver is 10.4 but I couldn't found the tag!

Thanks!

Comment: the query took 0.055ms + 0.021ms

Comment: Those are 0.008 milliseconds. Do you get the same results if you repeat the experiment? What is the network latency between client and server?

Comment: Your title is vague. And contains an important mispelling.

Comment: pgAdmin is known to be quite slow when it comes to _displaying_ results. This is not a Postgres performance problem, but a pgAdmin problem.

Comment: Is that a cloud instance? Maybe Azure PostgreSQL on Basic subscription?

Comment: @edouard-h so query took 0.076 ms. Do you know what is the meaning of "actual time=0.008"?

Comment: @Laurenz-albe Yes, almost same results around that numbers. Server is not allowed to respond ping so not sure how to measure network latency. Do you know what is the meaning of 0.008 ms? Query time or?

Comment: @alex-yu Yes, it's a cloud instance, running on K8S as a pod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference must be network lag.

You could try with a query that does nothing really and see if you get a similar duration:

```
SELECT 1;
```

That should show the same duration and would confirm that there is a network latency of around 250 ms.

Comment: Yes, it took around 250 ms, so basically that time means "query time+ the time to get data to the laptop(pgadmin)" ? Do you know what is the exact query time then? 0.008 ms or (planning time+execution time)?

Comment: The query took 0.076 milliseconds (planning + execution), the sequential scan 0.008 milliseconds.

Comment: To make it clear, that ~250ms, which I saw on Pgadmin after running a query means that "query time+ the time to get data to the laptop(pgadmin)"?

Comment: That's the time the client measures between sending the client to the server and receiving an answer.